# Azure Data Studio Notebook: Maximum Call Stack size Exceeded

Tags: azure, azure-data-studio, azure-notebooks

I am using Azure Data Studio to write notebooks and run queries against a sql database instance.

When I try running two different cells I get the errore:

```
Maximum Call Stack size Exceeded.
```

Is there a way to allow parallel execution or even just make it so it executes the second cell as soon as the first cell completes (like in jupyter for example)?

Comment: Try to use latest version of azure data studio and confirm if same issue continues.

Comment: @PratikLad Hi, I updated to last version but I have the same issue

Comment: I tried running two cells simultaneously. Azure data studio supports executing two cells simultaneously. The error message "Maximum Call Stack size Exceeded" usually occurs when there is an infinite loop in the code. Check the code for any recursive function calls or loops that might be causing the issue. Try running the cells one at a time to check if error occurs.

Comment: yes sure, the commands I run all complete correctly, did you try running queries or programming code? maybe it happens only with queries...

Comment: @Aswin do you have an update on this?

Comment: I ran two SQL queries simultaneously in two cells. It worked.